# How to create webhook for pushes in 3rd party repo using the Github API

Tags: git, github, github-api, webhooks

How do I create a webhook for pushes in a repo I neither own nor have developer access to?

It's possible to create an account on github that uses gmail as its notification email, watch the repo and then create a Google App Script that listens for events on that address and asks Github API for recent changes. Though this seems like a serious overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without administrative access to the repository, you can't install any hooks, but there are still a couple simpler options than receiving emails:

- Poll the [Repository Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events)
- Subscribe to the repo's RSS feed at `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commits/<branch>.atom`. [Example](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master.atom)

Comment: Both ways are using polling :/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately only repo admins can configure pushes. Maybe you can convert it easily with something like IFTTT.

Comment: I've just sent this issue to Github support and they're saying this is intended and is not going to be fixed soon, surprisingly, because it's somehow more costly than getting constant polling DDoS.

Comment: I doubt this use is a significant percentage of their traffic :-D